# Data Cleaning and variable creation using R

Tags: r

I have  dataset which have five variables: year, month, day, propertycrimes and sunset. Sunset is equal to 1 for the hour of sunset and the hour after sunset. I want to Keep only the 25 days each year that are between March 9 and April 3, and I want to  Create a variable, Post2007, equal to 1 if the year is 2007 or later and equal to zero if the year is before 2007.

[Here's dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UMDZU3QZuiE2LhdGA9iiYL8svP8by7m_/view?usp=sharing)

year    month   day sunset  propertycrimes

2003      1      1    0         90

2003      1      1    1         4

2004      1      1    0         56

2004      1      1    1          4

2005      1      1    0          96

2005      1      1    1          10

2006      1      1    0          82

2006      1      1    1           5

2007      1      1    0          65

2007      1      1    1           7

```
library(readr)
dailycrimedataDD <- read_csv("dailycrimedataDD.csv")
View(dailycrimedataDD)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

could be done using `dplyr`

```
  short <- dailycrimedataDD %>%
    filter((month == 3 & day >= 9 ) | (month == 4 & day <= 3))  %>%
    mutate(Post2007 = if_else(year >= 2007,1,0))
```